# How to unbind a child element from parent's event listener (without jQuery)?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an accordion where you can click on a list of names and it reveals a bio underneath. I would like to unbind the child element bios from being able to toggle open/close the clicked profile. Is it possible to unbind a child element from a parent's click event listener? I'd prefer to do it in Javascript, without jQuery.

I thought maybe using css and setting pointer-events to 'none' would do it, but the javascript click listener overrides it.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide an example of your HTML and the script called by the onclick events?

Answer (score 0):

You can just allow the clicks, but put a filter in your parent's click handler to see which was the element clicked on, with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Let's say you have `parent` set to a name/profile element:

```
profile.onclick = function(e) {
    // verify the click happened on this element, not on a child:
    if (e.target !== this) return false; // exit
    // collapse/expand code comes here
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question, or could you give some feedback?